# NSJSONSerialization with C# Rest Service

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, json

So I'm a complete noob with C# and web stuff and trying to figure something out.  There is some code that says this:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "People", Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string GetPeople() {
   Person results = DataAccess.ParsePeople();
   System.WebScrip.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = oSerializer.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
   string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(results);
   return sJSON;
```

}

When I type in the url for this method, my response looks like:

```
"{\"AddressesCollection\":[{\"Street\":\"1234 Temp Dr\",\"Zip\":94011},{\"Street\":\"56789 Nothing Dr\",\"Zip\":2222},\"ErrorMessage\":\"SUCCESS\"}"
```

I was trying to follow this tutorial on the iPad side: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Looking at the website they used as an example, the JSON output looks like:

{"paging":{"page":1,"total":4440,"page_size":20,"pages":222},"loans":[{"id":447290,"name":"Rosa","description":{"languages":["es","en"]},"status":"fundraising","funded_amount":0,"basket_amount":0,"image":{"id":1134583,"template_id":1},"activity":"Animal Sales","sector":"Agriculture","use":"to buy barnyard fowl and feed.","location":{"country_code":"PE","country":"Peru","town":"M\u00f3rrope - Lambayeque","geo":{"level":"country","pairs":"-10 -76","type":"point"}},"partner_id":143,"posted_date":"2012-07-13T19:00:05Z","planned_expiration_date":"2012-08-12T19:00:05Z","loan_amount":400,"borrower_count":1},{"id":447292,"na

On the iPad, when I do:

```
NSDictionary *fields = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

or

```
NSArray *fields = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

both are empty.  Is it the output of the C# that is not proper JSON?  Thanks.

Comment: Your Json string (starting with `AddressesCollection`) is not valid

Comment: @L.B Is that because of the JavaScriptSerializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON string is missing a closing `]` somewhere.

Assuming the string you posted is exactly what was returned by the server, you will also probably need to remove the backslashes in order to make it valid JSON.

```
NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:response] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
NSDictionary *fields = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseString options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: Do you happen to know if the C# code is causing the output to look like that with the backslashes around every string object?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is.  See [this reference](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/) for more information as well as a potential solution.